# Java InputStreamReader tries to read whole stream?

Tags: java, inputstreamreader

I'm trying to read UTF-16 string from a `Socket`. And the point is I don't know its length in bytes before I read first few chars of the string.

So I've opened `InputStreamReader` like this:

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-16");
```

And then I tried to read it char by char.

```
reader.read();
```

And it hangs while trying to read the very first char!

In a process of debugging I realized that it looks like `InputStreamReader` kinda tries to read WHOLE `InputStream`, and then converts it to UTF-16 char sequence. And of course, it goes all the way down to end of string, and it's nothing there, so it just waits for the client to send some more bytes.

Is that really the way `InputStreamReader` works? If it is - how can I read a PART of UTF-16 `InputStream`, or better one single char, without reaching end of it?

Comment: Can you try -   new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-16"));

Comment: ``read()`` blocks until data is available. So if it blocks, the stream is empty.

Comment: "I assume you haven't read the documentation" - I've read it, and InputStream works as it should. Returns bytes up to the end of string and then hangs.

Comment: Charset.forName("UTF-16") - Tried, didn't help.

Comment: "the stream is empty" - Nope

Comment: The InputStream is definitely not empty. I even tried to wrap it with another stream and sysout'ed all the "read()" calls. And yes, InputStreamReader calls it up to the end of stream.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a `BufferedReader` like the documentation says?

Comment: Yeah, it was wrapped from the start, and then I "unwrapped"  it to solve this bug)

Comment: It may be obvious, but have you tried the tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it in despair, and obviously, it didn't work, because that "buffering" behaviour is what I'm trying to get rid of :)

Answer (score -1):

if i understand you pb you should translate your inputstream into a string using a byte[] with

```
IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

then you should be able to iterate on it

or directly

```
FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(path))
```

if you want to get a byte[] from the file

Comment: No, the point is "I don't know its length before I read first few chars". Therefore, I can't just read the whole stream - it will block the thread at the end.

Comment: and if you translate you input into a byte[] in order to read its length

Comment: using IOUtils.toByteArray(Input) you'll get your byte[] then you can get the size

Comment: I can't translate my input to a byte[], because it's a socket. And a socket works that way it WAITS endlessly for new bytes, not ends the stream.

Comment: i don't know how to help you then :/

Answer (score -1):

As the BufferedInputStream method you are using does not block you get the situation that as soon as your InputStream does not have any data and is not closed you don't get a -1 but a 0. This will send your method into an endless loop.

So for reading local streams it is better to check for read() <= 0 as you usually get the data fast enough.
The best way is to make sure there is an eof by closing the stream.

Comment: Hmm, wait a sec, it doesn't return 0. It blocks.

Comment: Show your code with which you are trying to do this

Comment: InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-16");
reader.read();

Comment: Where is your loop?

Comment: There is no loop. I'm trying to read first char and it blocks. InputStream is not empty.